# How to config radrails for rails project to run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radrails

I searched a lot about how to config radrails to run rails project, and stuck here for a long time.
Here is what I did: 
 
install ruby,rails in windows (ruby -v and rails -v both returns version correctly 
 
install mysql 
Then  
 
1. download radrails and install 
 
2. From some online tips it said: radrails->window->preference, select rails->config and add the rails path, but how come I did not see the config menu? my one only shows autest and haml
 
3.Then I created a rails project and try to start it, always get this error:**Resource '/company/public' does not exist.**
 
 
 
 
Anybody can help me out? stuck here for hours.....are there any documentation for this? 
 Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution that worked for me was to downgrade the rails version.

https://radrails.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/327-resource-projectnamepublic-does-not-exist/page/1